Line art don't go though an alpha material
I've made a small scene on Blender, trying to get an image of a ping pong table "cartoon style".

The problem is this: When I try to render, the net block the line art

I guess this happens because I've create a material whit alpha = 0, but the camera still see the plane.
(to create the net I've subdivide a plane, mark freestyle edge foreach line of the net and set the alpha of the material to 0)
There is an option to get the lineart "overlap" behind a plane?

Model the net with actual geometry, rather than a plane with alpha
